# React.js server-side rendering with moment.js dependency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, momentjs

I'm using the [react-rails](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails) gem and I have it configured to render correctly on the server-side using the instructions provided in the readme, ie:

```
# Gemfile    
gem "therubyracer", platforms: :ruby
```

My view:

```
# show.html.erb
<%= react_component('BlahApp', { something: @user.something, stuff: @user.stuff }, { prerender: true }) %>
```

I do have one component that heavily uses moment.js through the [momentjs-rails](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=23i8BzhxCy8) gem, and I can't seem to get server-side rendering to work with that:

```
Encountered error "ReferenceError: moment is not defined"
```

moment.js is correctly included in the assets pipeline by Sprockets, but I suspect that isn't happening on the server side.

What's the correct way to include additional JS libraries for server-side rendering with React, whether through these gems or in general?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provide any code example how you are setting it up right now but from what you have described the best way is to use `require()` on both backend and frontend.

`require()` works on node.js out of the box. To achieve the same effect in browser you can use [browserify](http://browserify.org/).

Comment: I've updated the code. So it looks like I'm going to need Browersify to get the additional stuff to be properly processed on the server side render. Will try and report back!

Comment: Yes, also take a look on additional plugins like coffeeify, reactify if you are writing your code using CoffeeScript and/or JSX.